# Kannel SqlBox not working... Showing error: Trying to fetch variable `ssl-client-cipher-list' in group `sqlbox', not allowed

Tags: sms-gateway, kannel, wap

Kannel bearerbox version `1.4.5'. Compiler` 11.2.0'. System Linux, release 5.15.0-71-generic, version #78-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 18 09:00:29 UTC 2023, machine x86_64. Hostname xx.xx.xx.xxx, IP xx.xx.xx.xxx. Libxml version 2.9.12. Using OpenSSL 3.0.0 7 sep 2021. Compiled with MySQL 8.0.27, using MySQL 8.0.33. Compiled with PostgreSQL 14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-1ubuntu1). Using SQLite 3.36.0. Using hiredis API 0.14.1 Using native malloc.

kannel and smsbox is working fine but Sqlbox showing error.

installing SqlBox through this command: (sqlbox-0.7.2)

```
**sudo apt-get install kannel-sqlbox**
```

and my configuration file is (sqlbox.conf)

```
group = sqlbox
id = sqlbox-db
smsbox-id = sqlboxx
#global-sender = ""
bearerbox-host = localhost
bearerbox-port = 13001
smsbox-port = 13005
smsbox-port-ssl = false
sql-log-table = sent_sms
sql-insert-table = send_sms
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/kannel-sqlbox.log"
log-level = 0
#ssl-client-certkey-file = ""
#ssl-server-cert-file = ""
#ssl-server-key-file = ""
#ssl-trusted-ca-file = ""
```

## Database connection examples. Please uncomment as needed

```
group = mysql-connection
id = sqlbox-db
host = localhost 
username = myuser
password = mypass
database = kannel
```

[image]

Please check and help to fix this error. I have done a lot of R&D but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

which worked for me,

Please locate this file sqlbox-cfg.def located in add-ons, sqlbox/gw directory
open the file edit it modify the file as below

SINGLE_GROUP(sqlbox,
OCTSTR(id)
OCTSTR(smsbox-id)
OCTSTR(global-sender)
OCTSTR(bearerbox-host)
OCTSTR(smsbox-port)
OCTSTR(smsbox-port-ssl)
OCTSTR(sql-log-table)
OCTSTR(sql-insert-table)
OCTSTR(log-file)
OCTSTR(log-level)
OCTSTR(bearerbox-port)
OCTSTR(limit-per-cycle)
OCTSTR(save-mo)
OCTSTR(save-mt)
OCTSTR(save-dlr)
OCTSTR(ssl-client-certkey-file)
OCTSTR(ssl-server-cert-file)
OCTSTR(ssl-server-key-file)
OCTSTR(ssl-trusted-ca-file)
OCTSTR(ssl-client-cipher-list)
OCTSTR(ssl-server-cipher-list)

- OCTSTR(sql-engine)
  )

reconfigure the sqlbox and that should fix the issue.